# Redirection on domain name

Tags: redirect

I'm currently debugging a Dutch WP website https://glaszetterdirect.nl
The problem is that I get an unwanted redirect from: http://www.glaszetterdirect.nl to https://glaszetterdirect.nl/wp-admin

I really don't understand what's going on. I have already checked the following:

- `.htaccess`
- `wp-config.php`
- `wp_options` db table (`siteurl` and `home` both: `https://glaszetterdirect.nl`)
- Checked and deleted `wp_old_slug_redirect`
- Downloaded WordPress and FTP-ed this to my server

The strange thing is everything else is redirected the way it should.

Comment: Maybe a plugin (or custom code) on your site is forcing non-HTTPS requests to the WordPress admin page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `$ curl -I https://glaszetterdirect.nl` you can see the the response charset is `UTF-8` which indicates the redirect is done by Wordpress, not the webserver.

```
$ curl -I http://www.glaszetterdirect.nl

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 05 Oct 2018 08:24:41 GMT
Expires: Fri, 05 Oct 2018 09:24:42 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Location: https://glaszetterdirect.nl/wp-admin/
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Backend: web02_vmm22
Server: PCX/Cache
Age: 2483
X-Cache-Hit: Yes
X-Cache-Hits: 3
X-Server: cache01
Connection: keep-alive
```

While trying to access `http://www.glaszetterdirect.nl/wp-admin` will redirect you to the trailingslash page with a `iso-8859-1` charset.

```
$ curl -I http://www.glaszetterdirect.nl/wp-admin

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 05 Oct 2018 09:10:14 GMT
Location: http://www.glaszetterdirect.nl/wp-admin/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Backend: web02_vmm22
Server: PCX/No-Cache
Age: 0
X-Cache-Hit: No
X-Cache-Hits: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

You should have a look into the installed plugins and custom code as suggested by @Sally CJ.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like Redirection plugin is the culprit.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem :-)